# Restrict users who sign up for groups from viewing all groups they have been assigned to

Tags: groups

Paul Scully

https://buildingoneamerica.org/civicrm/profile/create?gid=75&reset=1

Do you know if there is a way to offer for people to sign up for a group without all the groups they are assigned to (which are many) being visible. The link is above. I do not want them to see all the groups they are in.

I can't seem to figure this out. below is what it looks like when i sign up.

[image]

Comment: Hi Paul. Welcome to SE. It may help folk answer if they know your CMS since Drupal offers options that other CMS do not.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to **Contacts menu » Manage Groups**, you should be able to click the **Settings** link next to a group.  Set the *Visibility* to **User and User Admin Only** (see screenshot).  This should suppress the visibility of the groups on profiles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Profile, in Adv Settings, you can specify that anyone who submits the Profile gets joined to Group X. That may or may not be what you are asking. I suspect not.

For sites using Drupal (as appears to be case for yours) you can use webform_civicrm extension to finesse public facing forms and be much more specific about what the user sees in terms of Groups etc.